# Change only 1 emails DNS to use another server but keep the other ones in my server

Tags: domain-name-system, email, cpanel

So I came across a weird problem and I don't know if there's a way to solve it or not

Basically, I made a protonmail.com account and changed the DNS servers in my cPanel to theirs
Now, everything works perfectly except that I only want to use Protonmail only with 1 account!

Like,

account1@example.com
account2@example.com
account3@example.com
account4@example.com
account5@example.com

I want to only change the DNS of 1 of them only to use with Protonmail
Let's say the first one

Now, whenever someone sends a message to any of thse account it gets added to Protonmail
Which is expected

Now, the question is

How can I use Protonmail or any other server with just one account

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. That's not how e-mail works.

An external e-mail server attempting to send e-mail to example@example.com will simply look up MX for example.com, and hand the e-mail to the server listed as MX for example.com.

E-mail to *the entire* example.com goes to whichever server is listed as MX for that domain, in your case Protonmail's Mail Server.

That mail server can, based on a lookup table of some sort, decide what to do with the e-mail:

- Deliver it locally to a mailbox.
- Forward it to another mailserver.
- Return a error message to the sender.
- Discard it silently.

That's basically it. If you want different e-mail accounts to be handled by different mail servers, you can't configure this in DNS. You'd have to configure Protonmail to forward mail for accounts they don't handle to your mail server. They probably doesn't offer this service.

Then your alternative is to configure *your* mail server to forward mail matching account@example.com to Protonmail's MX. This requires that their system accepts not being MX. They probably have automated checks that will tell you that you have an error in this scenario, but it may work.